# Sniffing out objects out of a void method with Mockito?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a method to test, to make it simple:

```
public void someMethod(SomeObject object) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("SOMETHING ").append("ELSE");
    object.setSomething(sb.toString());
}
```

For now I am not really interested if the method `setSomething()` has properly worked. Instead I would like to see if what `sb.toString()` returns.

Is there a way to access the `StringBuffer sb` object with Mockito?

Comment: Maybe you can mock the setSomething method and take a look at the parameter

Comment: is SomeObject method has getter method?

Answer (score 3):

You could do simple verification based on a mock.

Create the mock, invoke method, verify the mock has been called with a given parameter a number of times.

```
@Test
public void doTest() {
    //Setup mock
    SomeObject mock = mock(SomeObject.class);

    //Call method
    someMethod(mock);

    //Verify
    verify(mock, times(1)).setSomething("SOMETHING ELSE");
}
```

One would also argue that refactoring the method under test to something like:

```
public String someMethod() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("SOMETHING ").append("ELSE");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

And the test of the method (that appends/merges strings) would be much easier to test without mocking anything.

Test would look like this:

```
@Test
public void doTest() {
    //Call method
    String result = someMethod();

    assertEquals("SOMETHING ELSE", result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is not a way to directly access the StringBuffer, unless you were to pass it in as a parameter. 
But you could use an argument captor and a mocked object to see what value object.setSomething() got called with.

```
ArgumentCaptor<String> arg = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
Object object = mock(Object.class);

someMethod(object)
verify(object).setSomething(arg.capture());
assertEquals("some string", arg.getValue());
```

see https://rwehner.wordpress.com/2010/02/23/mockito-some-useful-programming-examples/

Answer (score 0):

With Mockito’s spy feature, we can mock only those methods of a real object that we want to, thus retaining the rest of the original behavior .

```
 @Spy
 SomeObject obj =new SomeObject();

 @Test
public void shouldReturnSomething(){
        someMethod(obj);//calling someMethod
        assertEquals(obj.getSomething(), "SOMETHING ELSE"); //assuming SomeObject has getter method

    }
```